# How to send Bundle data in widget activity class in Android?

Tags: android, widget, bundle

How can i recieve a bundle data from another activity to my widget activity class? 
This is my mainactivity code to send bundle data

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,MyWidget.class);
    extras= new Bundle();
    extras.putString("FAJR", sfajr);
    extras.putString("ZUHR", sZuhr);
    extras.putString("ASR", sAsr);
    extras.putString("MAGRIB", sMagrib);
    extras.putString("ISHA", sIsha);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
```

But in my widget activity i cant recieve my bundle data?
how can i get data in my widget activity?

Comment: check this url may help u       

   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718426/send-data-from-app-to-widget

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434898/sending-data-to-my-homescreen-widget

Comment: check links may help u

Answer (score 0):

Code in your Current Activity -

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,MyWidget.class);
    extras= new Bundle();
    extras.putString("FAJR", sfajr);
    extras.putString("ZUHR", sZuhr);
    extras.putString("ASR", sAsr);
    extras.putString("MAGRIB", sMagrib);
    extras.putString("ISHA", sIsha);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Code in your MyWidget class.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
String fajr= bundle.getString("FAJR");       
String zuhr= bundle.getString("ZUHR"); 
String asr= bundle.getString("ASR"); 
String magrib= bundle.getString("MAGRIB"); 
String isha= bundle.getString("ISHA");
```

Comment: not working Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); in mywudget class

Answer (score 0):

Salam,

I am trying to help here. You may need to change your code to this :

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,MyWidget.class);
//    extras= new Bundle();
    intent.putString("FAJR", sfajr);
    intent.putString("ZUHR", sZuhr);
    intent.putString("ASR", sAsr);
    intent.putString("MAGRIB", sMagrib);
    intent.putString("ISHA", sIsha);
//    intent.putExtras(extras);
```

And then in your other activity :

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b = getIntent().getExtras();
String fajr = b.getString("FAJR");
...
```

As per this so question [Simple example for Intent and Bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876273/simple-example-for-intent-and-bundle)
Voilà, hope this help.